# How To Catch Exception DB::unprepared()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, pdo

I want to run SQL script file in Laravel 5.5 and I use `DB::unprepared($sql)` which is good so far. But I found that `DB::unprepared($sql)` seems didn't return any error `Exception`. I try with different method but still didn't work.

Here some `Exception` class that I tried: `\Exception, PDOException, \Illuminate\Database\QueryException`, but didn't work.

Try tried get `bolean` return from `DP::unprepared($sql)` by doing this `$return = DB::unprepared($sql); var_dump($return);` but always return `TRUE`

I tried using `DB::statement($sql)`, but it looks like use only for executing `statement` per `statement`. I need to run a whole sql file without any modification.

Could anyone help me how to catch any SQL script error? Any laravel function method that could help me catch SQL exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kenjiro, I'm sure you already solved your problem, one a half year past. But, if I nailed it, please mark my answer as it will help fellows with the same problem in the future. *This post was the first when googling and **it has no answer...***

Well, it seems that, like me, you were submiting a multistatement query to DB::unprepared.

Say:

```
$sql = '
    drop temporary table if exists tmp_data;

    create temporary table tmp_data
    select1 *
    from data;'

$result = DB::unprepared($sql)
```

Even with the typo in `select1`, the code will run and `$result` will be `true`.

To make it work as expected we have to submit each single statement:

```
$sql = 'drop temporary table if exists tmp_data;'

DB::unprepared($sql);

$sql = '
    create temporary table tmp_data
    select1 *
    from data;'

DB::unprepared($sql)
```

No need to check the result. The second call to `unprepared` will raise an exception.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but no, I haven't solved yet. Right now I just need to make sure everything is worked in SQL Editor, and place to my source. I'll try your solution tomorrow.

Comment: @Kenjiro, I'm glad to be of help. An update: a couple of hours before this message, the new version I wrote for the migration was deployed in production, and then the error finally surfaced. Actually, the original was `drop trigger if exists; create trigger; exec procedure;`, and the error was in the create trigger statement due to lack of privileges. I was pretty sure the problem was in the `create trigger`, but had no clue on why. We have no access to production and now the infra guys have data to guide them through the troubleshooting.

Comment: @Kenjiro, please, do not forget to up my answer if it proves useful, deal?

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with **try catch** :

```
    try { 
      //your code
    } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){ 
      dd($ex->getMessage()); 
      // Note any method of class PDOException can be called on $ex.
    }
```

Also check For Reference : [Check This out](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.html)

Comment: I have tried but no luck. I just update my question. I mention some exception that I have tried. I use Laravel 5.5